# how to assign one variable value into another variable in shell script

Tags: shell

I tried below shell code to get the value of `temp` as "good 1" and "good 2", but I was not able to.

```
hello_1="good 1"
hello_2="good 2"
for i in 1 2
do
temp="hello_$i"
echo $temp
done
```

I want to fetch `hello_1` and `hello_2` variables value into `temp` variable.
I tried  above script but I was not able to get values of `hello_1` and `hello_2` into `temp`. please help me.

Comment: May be try to concat like ${hello_${i}}. Try and let us know whether working or not. Also try to echo value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you using `bash 4` or higher, read about [indirect references](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html).  But to answer your question you can do

```
hello_1="good 1"
hello_2="good 2"
for i in 1 2
do
    eval temp="\$hello_$i"
    echo $temp
done
```

**output**

```
good 1
good 2
```

`eval` is usually considered `evil` in shell programming. Don't get in a habit of using it.

The key technique is that the `eval` provides a 2nd evaluation of the line. On the first pass it looks like

```
 eval temp="$hello_1"
```

Note how the `$i` is displayed as `1`, AND that the leading `\\` char is removed from `\$hello_1`, so 
 when the `eval` is executed the processing of the line takes the value of `$hello_1` variable and assigns it to `temp`, i.e.

```
 temp="good 1"
```

IHTH